# What server names are available when this is set up in the nginx config?

Tags: nginx

```
server_name  src.wordpress-develop.dev *.src.wordpress-develop.dev ~^src\.wordpress-develop\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.xip\.io$;
```

This line is taken from VVV - https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV

I just want to understand why such server_name is applied and what server names are available in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the value of server name is a space separated list of expressions. Let's look at the expressions one by one.

```
src.wordpress-develop.dev
```

This sets up serving for that literal domain name. So "http://src.wordpress-develop.dev" in a browser

```
*.src.wordpress-develop.dev
```

This one sets up any wildcard subdomain of the domain indicated. So things that would match are `foo.src.wordpress-develop.dev` or `foobar1234-5678.somethingelse.src.wordpress-develop.dev`

Finaly the regex one:

```
~^src\.wordpress-develop\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.xip\.io$;
```

The preceeding tilde (`~`) indicates that what follows is a regular expression. In this case, the regex is matching domains that start with `src.wordpress-develop.` (note that the `.`'s are escaped as `\.` so as not to invoke the regex wildcard character `.`).

These domains must then have 4 sets of any number of digits followed by a dot each. This looks alot like an IPv4 address so: `src.wordpress-develop.205.15.198.6.`

Finally, the regex indicates that the domain should end with `xip.io`, so a full domain that matches this rule is: `src.wordpress-develop.205.15.198.6.xip.io`. The semicolon at the end of this rule simply terminates the entire `server_name` expression.

[See the docs here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

As to why the authors of that software chose these, I can't tell you. In general, the server_name directive is used for [Virtual Hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped!